# How fix Bootstrap responsive grid with columns of unequal height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap responsive grid created. The grid works fine as long as all columns are of equal height. If one or more columns are of unequal height the whole layout is messed up.

```
I have created a jsfiddle so you may see the problem alive and fix it. Thanks!
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5523/

Comment: So you are talking about a situation where some items may have star ratings and some may not have that right??

Comment: Yes! and image size may also vary.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is a bit messy so let me just go through it

Comment: Just increase the result area by moving slider to see the wrong output

Comment: You can either go with `display:flex;` for equal height divs or use just one star on the other items with `color:transparent;` on it so it will take the height but will not be visible on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set a fixed width value from the following markup:

```
<div class="product-thumb transition" style="height: ___px;">
```

Or simply add the width property from the CSS file:

```
.product-thumb {
     height: _____px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if the height of some columns exceed the fixed height? In my scenario the height of the columns is non-predictable

Comment: @BubbaYakoza You can try implementing this: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: Sounds good. will give it a try but the solution does not work in firefox

Comment: @abramlimpin The link in your comment no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid to use JavaScript I just wrote script based on jQuery which handles equal height of childrens in parent element. As far as I tested works fine in Chrome, IE from 6 - 11, Firefox, Safari. Script does not depends on fixed values of height. Fully responsive, works fine on window re-size and with changes of the content on different breakpoints. Just make sure there is no height on children elements. Script works perfectly fine for my needs, but I am still testing.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <h1>Title One</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque accumsan enim dui, quis posuere arcu luctus non. Pellentesque ut tortor quis diam volutpat imperdiet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h1>Title Two</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque accumsan enim dui, quis posuere arcu luctus non.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h1>Title Three</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque accumsan enim dui, quis posuere arcu luctus non. Pellentesque ut tortor quis diam volutpat imperdiet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

p {
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: auto;
}

.column {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 31.33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function equalHeight(parent) {
    function innerFunction() {
        var columns = $(parent).children();
        var maxContentHeight = -1;

        columns.each(function() {

            // Wrap content of every column in additional div
            $(this).wrapInner('<div class="inner-height"></div>');

            // Find the value of highest content from all columns
            var content = $('.inner-height', $(this));
            var contentHeight = content.height();

            if(maxContentHeight < contentHeight) {
                maxContentHeight = contentHeight;
            }

        });

        // Select the talest column and add class to it
        columns.each(function() {
            var content = $('.inner-height', $(this));
            var contentHeight = $('.inner-height', $(this)).height();

            if(contentHeight === maxContentHeight) {
                $('.inner-height', $(this)).parent().addClass('talest');
            }
        });

        // Get height of the highest column
        var talestColumn = $('.talest').height();

        // Calculate remaining space of the column
        var remainingHeight = talestColumn - maxContentHeight;

        // Set same height to all columns
        columns.each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('talest')) {
                // Set height auto for the talest column
                $(this).css('height', 'auto');
            } else {
                // Set height of the talest column to the rest of the column
                $(this).css('height', maxContentHeight + remainingHeight);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        innerFunction(parent);
        $(window).resize(function() {
            // Remove class from talest column on window resize
            $('.talest').removeClass('talest');
            innerFunction(parent);
        });
    });
}

equalHeight('.container');
```